How to retrieve and display user profile photos stored in Firebase
An administrator using my frontend Angular application should be able to upload and then view any user's profile image. I am successfully uploading user images to a folder within  Firebase storage bucket specific to each tenant. I am returning a user object whose photoURL contains the path to the image like so:
https://storage.googleapis.com/myapp.appspot.com/mybucket%2Ftheimage.jpg

However, when I include this path in an img tag (<img [src]="this_path"/>) I get an access denied error.
Image uploading and image retrieval occur through Firebase API functions--"put" for uploading and retrieval of a new image path, and "get" whenever I am retrieving the selected user but not assigning a new image to him.
The question: how can I overcome the access denied error so that an administrator of my frontend application can view the photo of any selected user within the given tenant? Thank you.

When you upload an image to the Storage bucket, what is the exact download URL that is generated? If you try to use it inside the HTML tags, are you getting the expected result?

In my Observable that was "subscribing" to data from the route resolver and from updates to the user's photo, I had to add this statement:
switchMap((user: User) => from(getDownloadURL(ref(getStorage(), user.photoURL?.toString()))))
Now in my template I can use an async pipe to hydrate [src] for the image to be resolved.

Consider storing the result of getDownloadURL (a URL for the image with a download token attached) as photoURL for that user. This will save needing to pipe it through ref and getDownloadURL for every user.

Interesting idea. In my Firebase function, I'm starting with this:  user = await tenantAuth.updateUser(request.params.id, {photoURL: fileToSave.publicUrl()}); You are suggesting this: user = await tenantAuth.updateUser(request.params.id,
{photoURL: await getDownloadURL(ref(getStorage(), fileToSave.publicUrl()))}); Finishing with response.send(user); The problem is that I want users of my app to see their own photo, while admins can see any user's photo. The latter approach does not provide the needed access token for admins.
